# Understanding clamav signature

Tags: vba, signature, clamav

I am new to to Clamav. I have decoded a clamav signature using [clamav-unofficial-sigs](https://github.com/extremeshok/clamav-unofficial-sigs)
and it gives this as decoded signature .

```
signature decodes to:
???*CallByName?VbMethod??*RndR?
```

I was getting not output when trying to decode using sigtool.
The document , which signature flagged as virus is a doc file has macros, but i think the doc is clean.
Doing a little search in macros I found it has a line

```
CallByName myEvent, "do_work", VbMethod, enableParam1, enableParam2
```

I am not sure what this signature mean or what it has matched.

The question is:-

1. How to determine what a clamav signature matches ?
2. What meaning is conveyed by the signatures (are they regexes or some other matching sequences) ?
3. Does clamav does dynamic analysis ?

Thank you